# Adjust LinearLayout height after dynamic change of child ImageView

Tags: android, layout, resize, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

My problem is the following. In my app I have a captcha query to verify the user. In `DialogFragment` an `ImageView` that is suppose to hold the captcha initially is empty, image is set dynamically in the code after receiving the captcha.

Problem is that `LinearLayout` height is computed when `ImageView` is empty, so after I set it, the image pushes everything down to invisible area of the dialog window (since LinearLayout height is not `updated`).

[image: image height is wrap_content]

I am pretty sure this is the cause because I tried to set the image height to fixed value and effect was the following.

[image: image height is 55dp]

Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/captcha_linear"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/captcha_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/captcha_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="type captcha code here..."
        android:maxLength="14"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:id="@+id/button_captcha_refresh" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/button_captcha_submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas how could I somehow rerender `LinearLayout` after I set captcha image so that it would take in account new height value?

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I tried to call `invalidate` in LinearLayout in order to rerender it.

Edit 2:

As requested, here is part of my DialogFragment

```
public void refreshCaptcha(String b64captcha) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(b64captcha, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    linear.invalidate();
    linear.requestLayout();
}
```

Here is how View is created:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_captcha, container);
    getDialog().setTitle("Catpcha verification");
    activity = (LoginActivity) getActivity();
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.captcha_image);
    linear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.captcha_linear);
    captcha_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.captcha_input);
    /* ... button callback events skipped ... */
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling requestLayout() on your ImageView or LinearLayour after getting captcha?

Comment: Thanks @Kistamushken for quick feedback. Yes, I also tried to alter order of invalidate and requestLayout(). I called them only on LinearLayout object, should I also try it on ImageView?

Comment: I just tried to call requestLayout() on both objects (without calling invalidate) and it didn't make any change.

Comment: Can you please provide code of your DialogFragment?

Comment: Sure, I just updated the post, I didn't put entire DialogFragment, but I did put onCreateView and also method that updates the captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I found the solution on [that](http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.com/2013/08/dynamic-dialogfragment-android.html) blog. Turned out that wrapping entire layout into `RelativeLayout` solved the issue, I don't really know why (if someone knows I will be grateful for comments).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/captcha_linear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/captcha_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/captcha_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="type captcha code here..."
            android:maxLength="14"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Refresh"
            android:id="@+id/button_captcha_refresh" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:id="@+id/button_captcha_submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

After fix it looks like that:

[image]